# php - mysqli_fetch_assoc to to json encoded array works on most queries, but not on others (although the queries return valid results)

Tags: php, mysql, json, xmlhttprequest

So here's the code:

```
if ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result0)) {
  //Found a company - now show all maintenances for company
  $company_id = $fetch[0];
  $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT maintenancedb.maileingang, maintenancedb.bearbeitetvon, maintenancedb.startDateTime, maintenancedb.done, maintenancedb.id FROM maintenancedb WHERE maintenancedb.lieferant LIKE '$company_id'") or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

  if ($resultsrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array2 = array();

    while ($resultsrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $array2[] = $resultsrows;
      //var_dump($resultsrows);
    }
    echo json_encode($array2);
  }else {
    $jsonArrayObject = array(array('maileingang' => 'no maintenances for this lieferant in system.', 'bearbeitetvon' => '', 'startDateTime' => '', 'done' => '', 'id' => ''));
    echo json_encode($jsonArrayObject);
  }
} else {
  $jsonArrayObject = array(array('maileingang' => 'no such company in DB yet', 'bearbeitetvon' => '', 'startDateTime' => '', 'done' => '', 'id' => ''));
  echo json_encode($jsonArrayObject);
  exit;
}
```

So the first example returns a valid json array. Theres 4 rows of results. The var_dump spits out each row as an array, and then at the bottom is the json encoded array which gets shown in a table.

```
array(5) {
  ["maileingang"]=>
  string(19) "2018-11-21 14:46:43"
  ["bearbeitetvon"]=>
  string(7) "abcde"
  ["startDateTime"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["done"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "16"
}
array(5) {
  ["maileingang"]=>
  string(19) "2018-11-23 06:52:00"
  ["bearbeitetvon"]=>
  string(7) "abcde"
  ["startDateTime"]=>
  string(19) "2019-01-15 22:00:00"
  ["done"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "17"
}
array(5) {
  ["maileingang"]=>
  string(19) "2018-11-21 14:46:00"
  ["bearbeitetvon"]=>
  string(7) "abcde"
  ["startDateTime"]=>
  string(19) "2018-11-13 11:00:00"
  ["done"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "18"
}
array(5) {
  ["maileingang"]=>
  string(19) "2018-11-25 12:08:00"
  ["bearbeitetvon"]=>
  string(7) "abcde"
  ["startDateTime"]=>
  string(19) "2018-11-27 05:00:00"
  ["done"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "19"
}
[{"maileingang":"2018-11-21 14:46:43","bearbeitetvon":"abcde","startDateTime":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","done":"0","id":"16"},{"maileingang":"2018-11-23 06:52:00","bearbeitetvon":"abcde","startDateTime":"2019-01-15 22:00:00","done":"0","id":"17"},{"maileingang":"2018-11-21 14:46:00","bearbeitetvon":"abcde","startDateTime":"2018-11-13 11:00:00","done":"1","id":"18"},{"maileingang":"2018-11-25 12:08:00","bearbeitetvon":"abcde","startDateTime":"2018-11-27 05:00:00","done":"1","id":"19"}]
```

And now the example where the json array returns entirely empty. There is only one row returned (correctly), but somehow the json encoding seems to fail:

```
array(5) {
  ["maileingang"]=>
  string(19) "2018-12-07 15:33:00"
  ["bearbeitetvon"]=>
  string(7) "abcde"
  ["startDateTime"]=>
  string(19) "2018-12-12 13:00:00"
  ["done"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "23"
}
[]
```

Any idea why that is? There don't seem to be any illegal characters, etc. When I create the db connection btw I'm already stating `mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');`

**EDIT:** Oh I noticed the first query should actually return 5 results, but is only returning 4.. There is no for loop where I am accidentally starting at 0 or 1 or something, however.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - for those of you stumbling upon this later:

The interior if statement with a while statement inside was the problem:

```
if ($resultsrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array2 = array();

    while ($resultsrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $array2[] = $resultsrows;
      //var_dump($resultsrows);
    }
    echo json_encode($array2);
  }else {
    $jsonArrayObject = array(array('maileingang' => 'no maintenances for this lieferant in system.', 'bearbeitetvon' => '', 'startDateTime' => '', 'done' => '', 'id' => ''));
    echo json_encode($jsonArrayObject);
  }
```

The first if statement check `$resultsrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` checked the 0 result, so then the identical while check started at result 1.

Thats why result 0 (in the case where there was only 1) was not encoded at all, and in the case where there was more than 1, like in my first example with 5 results where only 4 were shown, the first one wasn't encoded.